# Variables not displayed in email

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript

Any ideas why I cannot see variables on my email template? I provide an array of variables and create a JSON request. SalesForce gives me 202 return with all my variables inside.

I get my email and yet there are no variables inside.

I set variables on SalesForce side like:

```
Var @orderId
Var @title
Set @orderId = AttributeValue("orderId")
Set @title = AttributeValue("title")
```

And use these variables as:

> %%=v(@orderId)=%%

and

> %%=v(@title)=%%

What could be wrong?

EDIT:

I call the API method with my Json data to send this email, here is the Json I am sending:

```
{"To":
  {"Address":"email@gmail.com",
   "SubscriberKey":"email@gmail.com",
   "ContactAttributes":
   {"SubscriberAttributes":
     {"orderId":"24706803",
     "title":"Test title"
     }
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Salesforce Marketing Cloud? If so, could you please add relevant tags to your question? This doesn't appear to be about `community` or `lightning-templates`.

Comment: Are you triggering this email via API?  If so, please update your question to include the JSON request that you mentioned.  If you could also outline what configuration steps you took in SFMC in preparation for making this API call, that would help.

Comment: API Json call added.